# How to disable sorting QueryString Parameters (React Router)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, query-string

I am trying to set a Route path with a query string. But react-router always sorts query params and shows alphabatically sorted querystring in URL.

For example, I have a location filter page where I add filters to my location list. If I filter "Pakistan": "Lahore", "India": "Delhi", and then "America": "Washington", the URL should look like:

`/Search?Pakistan=Lahore&India=Delhi&America=Washington`

But URL shows it as follows *(alphabetically sorted)*:

`/Search?America=Washington&India=Delhi&Pakistan=Lahore`

How can I disable this sorting feature in react-router?

Answer (score 0):

There is [an issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3713) about it.

**tl;dr** : You have to update your React Router version to `4.x`, the 'fix' of this issue will not be included in `3.x` future version. You can eventualy create a link with ordered querystring at the end instead of using query object [example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3713#issuecomment-239617721).